# Shader Graph, texture not looping

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I would like to make a shader using shadergraph, but i got a little problem.

I have a texture like this 
[image]

I would like to move over that texture over time to make some sort of laser effect, but it works only at start, cause when the time goes too high, my texture is a become a simple line
[image]

This lane appear even in shadegraph, if i go to much left or right on the offset of the texture, it doesn't loop, it just show the last point infinitely. I would like that when my texture end it loop back to the same texture forever

What do I miss pls ?

Comment: When adding an image to your question please make sure the quality is high enough to actually be able to read the settings...

Comment: sorry didn't noticed, edited

Comment: Nice that's much better!

Comment: Look at [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGGB5LFEejg) there is a `Tiling and Offset` node you can use to loop your texture

Answer (score 3):

Select your texture in the inspector, and set the Wrap mode to "Repeat".
(Or use a sampler state in the shader graph)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a node "sampler state" that you can pull out from/to the third input of Sample Texture 2D. which has a wrap:repeat field.